# Scroll to the end of the infinite loading page using selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm scraping the follower names from the twitter using Selenium and that page is infinite, whenever I scroll down I can see new followers.
Somehow I want to go to the bottom of the page so that I can **scrape** all the followers.

```
while number != 5:
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
   number = number + 1
   time.sleep(5)

usernames = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
       "css-4rbku5.css-18t94o4.css-1dbjc4n.r-1loqt21.r-1wbh5a2.r-dnmrzs.r-1ny4l3l")
for username in usernames:
   print(username.get_attribute("href"))
```

Right now code is scrolling 5 times. I have put a static value but I don't know how much scrolls are needed to reach the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below code for infinite loading. It will keep scrolling until new elements are getting loaded i.e. page size is changing.

```
# Get scroll height after first time page load
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page / use a better technique like `waitforpageload` etc., if possible
    time.sleep(2)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following script, there is no sleep time, hence it scrolls faster:

```
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 4
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    import datetime
    time_past = datetime.datetime.now()
    while (datetime.datetime.now() - time_past).seconds <=SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for scroll, but the listing did not load when I scrolled to the end of the page. The problem was in large footer, So I slightly corrected the above code and scrolled to the footer.

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 1300);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(2)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Maybe it will be useful for someone